# Does the Chopin Airport in Warzaw Poland really have just one Terminal?

Tags: airports, poland, power, warsaw

I will be connecting flights in Warsaw Poland soon and while researching the Chopin Airport I get the impression that it only has one terminal. Is this true or am I incorrect?

Also, if I need to charge my devices while waiting, do their electrical outlets/sockets allow USA based plugs or will I need to use an adapter?

Thanks!

Comment: I would bring an adapter, they are not big and not expensive, and work in most of Europe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All “normal” commercial flights are in terminal A. There is also a small terminal for general aviation (f.e. private aircraft, air taxis, air ambulances...).

Electrical outlets are type E (CEE 7/5). US plugs will not fit without an adapter. A simple adapter is cheap and lightweight. Electricity is 230V, 50Hz (vs 115V, 60Hz in the US). Most phone and computer chargers can handle both systems (with an adapter), but **you should check first**. There should be a marking on the equipment.

Comment: Thanks! You've cleared all my questions up for me!